# Unity countdown timer jumping to zero and counting down into negatives

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

Something strange is happening with my countdown timer and I'm stuck. I'm passing a number to my timer (15 seconds) which starts at 15 but then jumps to 0 and then counts down from there: 0, -1, -2, -3... What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    float seconds;
    public Text timerText;

    public void Update()
    {
        seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timerText != null)
        {
            timerText.text = Mathf.Round(seconds).ToString();
            Debug.Log (Mathf.Round(seconds));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the countdown script from a function in another script like this:

```
void ShowRestartWarning()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Restart Warning Dialog");

        canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");

        timerInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog);
        timerInstance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        timerInstance.SetActive(true);

        CountdownTimer countdownTimer = timeOutWarningDialog.GetComponent<CountdownTimer>();
        countdownTimer.Update();                                                    

        CancelInvoke();
        Invoke("RestartGame", countdownLength);   
    }
```

Comment: How do you start your timer? (how do you call `startTimer`?)

Comment: `Update()` is run automagically by MonoBehaviour. I think you might get some weird behaviours by running it yourself.

Comment: What is the the value of `Time.deltaTime` on the first run? And if `Update()` is run by the base class, shouldn't it have an override in `CountdownTimer`?

Comment: @Maakep I'm calling Update from another script to trigger the countdown. Is this not the way to do it?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel the value of Time.deltaTime is starting at zero even though I'm setting seconds to 15.

Comment: @greyBow No, you never want to manually call Update(). Unity calls it every frame for every object with a script that defines it/inherits it from MonoBehavior.

Comment: Show us how you call it, please. Make sure you are not calling it from multiple places at THE same time

Comment: @josephmbustamante how should i call this timer script from another script then?

Comment: @greyBow Make a custom method and call that., but don't use Update(). For example, you could create a method called `StartTimer()` and have that do it.

Comment: @josephmbustamante could you illustrate how to do that please? Would I need to use a coroutine?

Comment: @greyBow Yea, that's one way! In your `StartTimer()` method, you could have it start a coroutine with a `yield return WaitForSeconds(1)` -- I think that's the code for it. You'll also have to implement `IEnumerable`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a coroutine instead of Update function, that way you can start it and stop it whenever you want.

```
public Text timerText;

public void Start(int seconds)
{
    StartCoroutine("RunTimer", seconds);
}

IEnumerator RunTimer(int seconds)
{
    while (seconds > 0)
    {
        if (timerText != null)
        {
            timerText.text = seconds.ToString();
            Debug.Log (seconds);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        seconds -= 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    float seconds;
    public Text timerText;

    public void Update()
    {
        seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timerText != null)
        {
            timerText.text = Mathf.Round(seconds).ToString();
            Debug.Log (Mathf.Round(seconds));
        }
    }
}
```

First the `Update()` method in a MonoBehaviour that is activated it will be called every frame (More info about that here: [Execution Order of Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html))

Now, in your script you have 2 variables. First a private `seconds` and then a public `timerText`.
Why `timerText` is public? If that variable is not being used by another class should be `private`.

Now is when you ask; But how I attach a `Text` component in the editor? Well, you should use [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) instead.

Now I think that the error is that you are assigning some value to the Text component. But, your variable `seconds` is by default zero. (You are declaring a float without any value, by default it will be `initialized` as [0f](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table)).

So the first frame the Text component will display your initial value, let say `15`. But the first time that `Update()` is being called, the line `seconds -= Time.deltaTime` it will be something like `seconds = 0f - Time.deltaTime;`, then `timerText` it will be updated with this new `almost zero` value.

What can you do? You can use another Event Function, [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) to setup your variable with some value before the `Update` calls.

If you want to use the value of `timerText` you can do this:

```
public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float seconds;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text timerText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(timerText))
        {
            seconds = float.Parse(timerText.text);          
        }
    }

    // Yep, Event Functions can be private and Unity will `call` them anyways
    private void Update() 
    {
        seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timerText != null)
        {
            timerText.text = Mathf.Round(seconds).ToString();
            Debug.Log (Mathf.Round(seconds));
        }
    }
}
```